# Does DSL/VOIP Service Work In A Power Outage

Tags: voip, adsl

Just curious, but does DSL service work in a power outage? From what I know, DSL uses regular phone lines to transmit digital rather than analog signals at a higher speed, and regular phone service works fine in an outage as power is sent through the lines from the phone company.

If I use a VOIP service, and power the DSL modem and router off a generator (assuming that the phones lines aren't down), is it possible to make calls during an outage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The equipment needed to run both DSL and VoIP (the modem and VoIP box) require an outside power source to function. Unlike traditional pots line VoIP and DSL cannot use the existing DC current on a circuit. Some areas offer the capability of plugging in an ordinary handset to these lines to reach emergency services in the event of a power outage.

If you had battery backup or a generator, you'd be able to use your DSL and VoIP as the equipment on the other end would likely have an extensive battery backup as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a direct line to your DSLAM, this might work. Still, it depends on the network operator to supply emergency power to the DSLAM, which probably requires quite a lot of energy.

Long story short: VoIP will not be usable in case of a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to understand are two things here. VoIP needs a live Internet connection, and you must have juice for whatever end device you are using. Though the phone line, perse, may be having power, the modem and router do need juice to keep the connection live.

The end device has taken a completely different form today. With applications (http://telecom.toshiba.com/Telephone_Systems_Resources/Mobile-Apps/) installed on your Android or Apple iOS, your mobile phone can act as a powerful end device for all VoIP activities. Not just voice, but stuff such as unified communications etc.

VoIP is progressing very fast, and things like power outages can be easily overcome.